# Why kotlin recorded wav file is not understood by scipy?

Tags: python, kotlin, scipy, mediarecorder

I´m calling for the kind support of smart coders like you to solve a problem which required special skills.

I´m trying to record a wav file using MediaRecorder in a Kotlin android app. It´s works well, record and plays back.
My bottleneck is when processing this wav file with a python flask app, using scipy.wavefile.read.
I got error message like
“ValueError: File format b'\x00\x00\x00\x18' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.”

During the postmortem debug process, I downloaded the recorded file from the server,I mean, the audio went from the phone to the server and back to my computer. And it plays well on WindowsMediaPlayer and VLCm they recognize my file as .wav file. However, opening the file with notepad, I see the wav files which works with scipy starts with a  “RIFF$” string, while my recorded file doesn’t have that. Maybe is a hint of the problem. Dunno.

Here´s the kotlin code to record the file:

```
        val tmpRecordfile: File = 
        File.createTempFile("birdrec${System.currentTimeMillis()}", ".wav", requireContext().cacheDir)
        if (tmpRecordfile.exists()) recordingFilePath = tmpRecordfile.path.toString()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            recorder =  MediaRecorder(requireContext())
        }else {
            recorder =  MediaRecorder()
        }
        recorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        recorder!!.setAudioSamplingRate(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE) // is 44100
        // working wav file, but not recognized by Scipy
        recorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB)
        recorder!!.setOutputFormat(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
        recorder!!.setAudioChannels(1)
        recorder!!.setOutputFile(recordingFilePath)
```

Later on, when postin to the Flaks APP

```
                    val requestBody: RequestBody =
                        MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("audioFile", tmpRecordfile.name,File(tmpRecordfile.path).asRequestBody("audio/wav".toMediaType())
                            )
                            .build()

                    val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(serverURL).post(requestBody).build()
                    val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                    Log.d("Server response: ",response.body!!.string())
```

It travels well from the phone and when arrives to its  destination server, is receiving by this Python code:

```
        // Get file from post
        request.files['audioFile'].save(save_path)
        app.logger.info("Save received file in " + save_path )
        #continue processing...
        try:
            sampleIn, dataIn = wavfile.read(save_path)  #<-- this line is responsible for my misery 
        except Exception:
            app.logger.info("Error reading wav file  " + save_path)
```

Then is when I got the Error message: ValueError: File format b'\x00\x00\x00\x18' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.

Maybe my wave file is not truly a wav file, something is missing, maye that “RIFF$” string at the beginning, but I don’t know how to fix.

Any hints on this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In VLC, what does the codec info panel tell you?

Comment: @Reinderien, it shows no information, neither with the .wav which works. Bur is strange that Audacity does not recognize it...

Comment: UPDATE: I realize MediaRecorder doesn't generate .WAV files.  Since Scipy olne reads .WAV, my choices are either (A) find another way of saving the recording in .WAV (B) or finding anothet library to correlate (FFT)  my audio files in 3GPP format.  There is a wonderful lib, librosa, but is based in FFMPEG, which in not allowed on my shared hosting, where I have my SSL certifcates, required by Android. I could try a cloud service that allows FFMPEG...thats my option (C), not sure about the certificates.

Comment: I realize the problem is MediaRecorder doesnt save in WAV format. To do that, we need
(1)  to use AudioRecorder to save the raw audio data, as suggested [here](https://dolby.io/blog/recording-audio-on-android-with-examples/), 
and (2) take that raw data to save as wave file, you need to write the wav file byte per byte. I finally was able to write the [wave headers](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/), byte per byte.

Now my wave file is played by media players, but still not understood by SCIPY, which is asking for 8 bytes more....

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer hoping to help late comers, especially because it was hard to find answers that guided my to the solution. I really need to deal with bytes.

The problem was MediaRecorder doesn't save in WAV format. Posting raw data as "audio/wa" MIME type doesn't make it a wave file. Just as nobody becomes a ninja just by wearing a kimono ;)

To get the wave file, we need:

(1)  to use AudioRecorder instead of Media Recorder, to save the raw audio data, as suggested [here](https://dolby.io/blog/recording-audio-on-android-with-examples/),

(2) take that raw data to save as wave file, you need to write the wav file byte per byte, adding the Wave headers.

(3) Adjust the WAVE headers to avoid "premature end of file" error from Scipy

Here's the working code (quick and dirty approach) for (1) to record raw data with AudioRecord:

```
 //First check whether the above object actually initialized
            if (audioRecord!!.state != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                //return
                Log.e("[some tag]", "Audio record no inicializado")
            }

            // assign size so that bytes are read in in chunks inferior to AudioRecord internal buffer size
            isRecordingAudio = true

            val data = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE_RECORDING / 2)
            var outputStream: FileOutputStream? = null

            //Now start the audio recording
            audioRecord.startRecording()

            //rECORDING Thread Start
            Thread{

                try {
                    outputStream = FileOutputStream(tmpRecordfile)
                } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                    Log.e("[some tag]", "tmpRecordfile access fail"+ e.message)
                    
                }

                while (isRecordingAudio) {
                    val read = audioRecord!!.read(data, 0, data.size)
                    try {
                        outputStream!!.write(data, 0, read)
                        // clean up file writing operations
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e("[some tag]", " writing audio into tmpFile>> file access fail"+ e.message)
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
```

In the code for part (2) I try to save the raw data into WAV file, adding the wav headers to the raw data obtained in the first part. The critical part is the header byte per byte, (i) according to the [WAVE standard](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) and (ii) using [little-endian format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), required by WAVE. In simple words, the bytes are written backwards, instead of writing "00 01" for int value 16 in HEX, you write "01 00".

At this point, if you can run away, please do! The following coding is intended to help karmic souls to pay for their sins writing bytes ;)

Before you code, you need to arm with a special weapons. As you need to understanding the wave headers as explained here:

[image]

The essential tool will be a HEX editor and a some Hex to decimal converter.

I used Notepad+ with a HEX plugin to check the bytes in the file. Also a online converter from HEX<> DEC, using little endian encoding [as this online converter](https://www.save-editor.com/tools/wse_hex.html)
Example, the fist 4 bytes have the strinf "RIFF" but the following has the size of your file. IS necessary to check if the value, in hex using little endian enconding, is the same as the size of your file. This verification is required for every byte described in the wave standard.

Here's an example of my wave headers:

[image: Wave headers on notepad+]

Follows the continuation of the code.

Ahh important: in this kotlin I use thread for the recording and buffered sinks for the data management ;)

```
while (isRecordingAudio) {
        val read = audioRecord!!.read(data, 0, data.size)
        try {
            outputStream!!.write(data, 0, read)
            // clean up file writing operations
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("LOG TAG", " writing audio into tmpFile>> file access fail"+ e.message)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    try {
        // SAVE AS WAVE ------------------------------------
        //Create the file used to storage the mixed audio file.

        //Open the buffer for this file.
        //val bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.appendingSink(file))
        val bufferedSink = finalAudioFile.appendingSink().buffer()

        //Data header of the file.
        val header = Buffer()
        //Data of the file.
        val audioData = Buffer()

        // copy tmpFile in  tempBuffer
        tmpRecordfile.source().buffer()?.let { file ->
            //Create a new buffer for every audio address.
            val buffer = Buffer()
            //Read every byte on the buffer.
            file.readAll(buffer)
            //Get the buffer and write every byte on the sink.
            audioData.writeAll(buffer)
            //Close the sink.
            buffer.close()
            file.close()
        }
        //Count of bytes on the data buffer.
        val fileSize = audioData.size.toInt()
        //The data is ready to be written on the sink.
        audioData.close()

        val totalFileSize = fileSize + 44 // The size of the raw data plus 44 bytes of the wave headers
        //
        val fileSizeSCIPY = totalFileSize - 8 // For some reason, scupy ask for a filesize 8 bytes less.. dont ask me why
        val byteRate = (RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNELS * BITS_PER_SAMPLE ) / 8
        val blocklAlign:Int = ( CHANNELS * BITS_PER_SAMPLE ) / 8

        Log.e("LOG TAG", "Raw file size: "+ fileSize.toString() +" Final file size: "+totalFileSize.toString())
        Log.e("LOG TAG", "Block align: "+ blocklAlign.toString() +" byteRate: "+byteRate.toString())
        Log.e("LOG TAG", "BITS_PER_SAMPLE: "+ BITS_PER_SAMPLE.toString() +" CHANNELS: "+CHANNELS.toString())
        Log.e("LOG TAG", "AUDIO_FORMAT: "+ AUDIO_FORMAT.toString())

        //Write the header of the final file.
        header.writeUtf8("RIFF")
            //Write the total file size (with the header) OK!
            .writeByte(fileSizeSCIPY and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSizeSCIPY shr 8) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSizeSCIPY shr 16) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSizeSCIPY shr 24) and 0xff)
            //Write the total file size (with the header)
            //.writeIntLe(totalFileSize) // checking
            //.writeIntLe(Integer.reverseBytes(totalFileSize))
            //      .writeIntLe(fileSize) //Inform the size of the chunk, including the header.
            .writeUtf8("WAVE") //Inform the type of file.
            .writeUtf8("fmt ") //Add the "fmt" letters
            // size subchuck
            .writeByte(16)
            .writeByte(0)
            .writeByte(0)
            .writeByte(0)
            //.writeByte(0)
            //.writeByte(0)
            //.writeByte(1)// 16 for PCM e tanto faz LE o BE
            .writeByte(1) // PCM =1
            .writeByte(0)
            //.writeByte(1)  // tanto faz LE o BE
            //.writeByte(CHANNELS)
            .writeByte(CHANNELS)
            .writeByte(0)
            // Sample rate OK!!
            //.writeIntLe(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE) //fmt chunk
            .writeByte(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE and 0xff)
            .writeByte((RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE shr 8) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE shr 16) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE shr 24) and 0xff)
            //Write the byte rate -- OK!!
            .writeByte(byteRate and 0xff)
            .writeByte((byteRate shr 8) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((byteRate shr 16) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((byteRate shr 24) and 0xff)
            //.writeIntLe(byteRate)
            .writeByte(blocklAlign) // tanto faz ??
            .writeByte(0)
            .writeByte(BITS_PER_SAMPLE) //Bytes per sample
            .writeByte(0)
            .writeUtf8("data")
            //File content size
            //.writeIntLe(fileSize)
            //fileSize for SCIPY with 8 bytes less -
            .writeByte(fileSize and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSize shr 8) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSize shr 16) and 0xff)
            .writeByte((fileSize shr 24) and 0xff)
            .close()

        // Buffered Sink es finalAudioFile
        with (bufferedSink) {
            writeAll(header)
            writeAll(audioData)
            close() //Close and write the file on the memory.
        }

        // continue
        outputStream?.flush()
        outputStream?.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("LOG TAG", "exception while closing output stream $e")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}.start() // end recording
```

Hope this code helps anyone who need to save wave files to be used in scipy or anywhere else. If it does, please rate and comment! ;)